# Understanding CEILING macro use cases

Tags: c, macros, ceil

I've found the following macro in a utility header in our codebase:

```
#define CEILING(x,y) (((x) + (y) - 1) / (y))
```

Which (with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020047/904767)) I've parsed as:

```
// Return the smallest multiple N of y such that:
//   x <= y * N
```

But, no matter how much I stare at how this macro is used in our codebase, I can't understand the value of such an operation. None of the usages are commented, which seems to indicate it is something obvious.

Can anyone offer an English explanation of a use-case for this macro? It's probably blindingly obvious, I just can't see it...

Comment: A more intuitive constraint: `x / y <= N`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you want to allocate memory in chunks (think: cache lines, disk sectors); how much memory will it take to hold an integral number of chunks that will contain the `X` bytes? If the chuck size is `Y`, then the answer is: `CEILING(X,Y)`

Comment: I upvoted all answers since they were all helpful in different ways. However, this answer is simple and direct, and gives me an easy way to consider the operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you use an integer division in C like this

```
y = a / b
```

you get a result of division rounded *towards zero*, i.e. `5 / 2 == 2`, `-5 / 2 == -2`. Sometimes it's desirable to round it another way so that `5 / 2 == 3`, for example, if you want to take minimal integer array size to hold `n` bytes, you would want `n / sizeof(int)` rounded up, because you want space to hold that extra bytes.

So this macro does exactly this: `CEILING(5,2) == 3`, but note that it works for positive `y` only, so be careful.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... English example... You can only buy bananas in bunches of 5. You have 47 people who want a banana. How many bunches do you need? Answer = CEILING(47,5) = ((47 + 5) - 1) / 5 = 51 / 5 = 10 (dropping the remainder - integer division).

Comment: Damn those banana merchants and their stubborn sales tactics! Thanks, though. It is good to step back from thinking in technical terms to understand things in a broader sense.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try some test values

```
CEILING(6, 3) = (6 + 3 -1) / 3 = 8 / 3 = 2 // integer division
CEILING(7, 3) = (7 + 3 -1) / 3 = 9 / 3 = 3
CEILING(8, 3) = (8 + 3 -1) / 3 = 10 / 3 = 3
CEILING(9, 3) = (9 + 3 -1) / 3 = 11 / 3 = 3
CEILING(10, 3) = (9 + 3 -1) / 3 = 12 / 3 = 4
```

As you see, the result of the macro is an integer, the smallest possible `z` which satisfies: `z * y >= x`.

We can try with symbolics, as well:

```
CEILING(k*y, y) = (k*y + y -1) / y = ((k+1)*y - 1) / y = k
CEILING(k*y + 1, y) = ((k*y + 1) + y -1) / y = ((k+1)*y) / y = k + 1
CEILING(k*y + 2, y) = ((k*y + 2) + y -1) / y = ((k+1)*y + 1) / y = k + 1
....
CEILING(k*y + y - 1, y) = ((k*y + y - 1) + y -1) / y = ((k+1)*y + y - 2) / y = k + 1
CEILING(k*y + y, y) = ((k*y + y) + y -1) / y = ((k+1)*y + y - 1) / y = k + 1
CEILING(k*y + y + 1, y) = ((k*y + y + 1) + y -1) / y = ((k+2)*y) / y = k + 2
```

You canuse this to allocate memory with a size multiple of a constant, to determine how many tiles are needed to fill a screen, etc.

Watch out, though. This works only for positive `y`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`CEILING(x,y)` gives you, assuming `y > 0`, the ceiling of `x/y` (mathematical division). One use case for that would be a prime sieve starting at an offset `x`, where you'd mark all multiples of the prime `y` in the sieve range as composites.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was long ago, but i found the reason of why you would use such macro, see in C++ you have the std defined [ceil(double x)](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/), but it actually has a flaw: when you try to perform division inside it you would get  the argument passed as an rounded number. Consider this codeforces problem: [B. Long Legs](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1814/B). It is solved using a brute force on this formula:

[image]

Now if you use std ceil you would get completely wrong values because of that type cast in the arguments;

```cpp
main(){
    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
      ll a , b;
      cin >> a >> b;
      ll k = a+b;
      for(ll i = 2; i <= 10e5;i++){
        ll val = std::ceil(a/i) + std::ceil(b/i) + i-1;
        k = min(k , val);
      }
      cout << k << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output (Wrong)**

```
1
4
5
```

Now using correct macro

```cpp
#define ceil(x,y) (((x) + (y) - 1) / (y))

main(){
    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
      ll a , b;
      cin >> a >> b;
      ll k = a+b;
      for(ll i = 2; i <= 10e5;i++){
        ll val = ceil(a,i) + ceil(b,i) + i-1;
        k = min(k , val);
      }
      cout << k << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output (Correct)**

```
2
5
6
```

If you still want to use std::ceil you can do it like this:
`std::ceil((double)a/i) + std::ceil((double)b/i) + i-1;`